# Webdriverio: Accessing shadow dom elements

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, webdriver-io, shadow-dom

```
I have an app structure like this: 
<shell>
#shadow-root (open)
<mini-app>
#shadow-root (open)
<input id="username" autocomplete="off" name="username" type="text" aria-required="true" required="" value="">
</mini-app>
<shell>
Nested tags with shadow-root element username inside it.I want to access input element username using webdriverio.
```

I am able to access username in dev  using the following:

```
   let a = document.querySelector('shell')
    let b = a.shadowRoot.querySelector('mini-app')
    b.shadowRoot.getElementById('username')

  How can i access the same using webdriverio ? I went through this `https://webdriver.io/blog/2019/02/22/shadow-dom-support.html` but the documentation looks outdated because I am unable to use shadowRoot with shadow$
Any help would be appreciated.
```

Is there any other way to access shadow dom elements through webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation seems to be fine, can you show how exactly you are using shadow$ method?

I belive that simple

```
$('shell').shadow$('.mini-app').shadow$('#username')
```

should work

Comment: I tried this but it throws the following error:
Error: Function selector "function() {
// element has a shadowRoot property
if (this.shadowRoot) {
return this.shadowRoot.querySelector('mini-app')
}
// fall back to querying the element directly if not
return this.querySelector('mini-app')
}" did not return an HTMLElement

Comment: Probably because its a nested shadow-root

Comment: I overlooked that this is nested shadow DOM. Try:

$('shell').shadow$('.mini-app').shadow$('#username')

Comment: When I tried this answer `$(...).shadow$ is not a function` - what is that about?